# Show differentiability of parametric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let be $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha<\beta$ and $G:=\{M\times [\alpha,\beta]=\{{ x\choose t} \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\mid x\in M, t\in [\alpha.\beta]\}$.

Consider the continuous function $K:G\to \mathbb{R}, {x\choose t}\to K(x,t)$. Further, let's assume that the partial derivatives of $K$ with regard to $(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$ exist and are continuous on $M$.

> Show that $F:M\to\mathbb{R}$ with $F(x):=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}K(x,t)dt$ is continuosly differentiable and that the partial derivatives of $F(x)$ satisfy: $D_iF(x)=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(x,t)dt$.
>
> (where $D_iK(x,t)$ denotes the partial derivatives with respect to $x_i$)

---

**My approach:**

Let be $a=(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ an arbitrary point of $M$. We define $\varphi_i:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\varphi_i(x_i)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,x_i,a_{i+1},\cdots, a_n)$. Next, we consider:
$$\frac{(F\circ\varphi_i)(x_i)-(F\circ\varphi_i)(a_i)}{x_i-a_i}=
\frac{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}K(\varphi_i(x_i),t)dt-\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)dt}{x_i-a_i}\\=
\frac{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}\left(K(\varphi_i(x_i),t)-K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)\right)dt}{x_i-a_i}.
$$
We know that $(K\circ \varphi_i)$ is differentiable with respect to $x_i$ (chain rule) and are allowed to apply the mean value theorem which supports us with an $\xi\in(a_i,x_i)$ such that:
$$
\frac{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)(x_i-a_i)dt}{x_i-a_i}=\frac{(x_i-a_i)\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)dt}{x_i-a_i}=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)dt.
$$
By assumption $D_iK(x,t)$ is continuous and therefore $D_iK(x,t)(x_i-a_i)$ and $\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(x,t)(x_i-a_i)dt$ are also continuous (we know this statement from lecture). As $\lim\limits_{x_i\to a_i}$ implies $\lim\limits_{\xi\to a_i}$ we can simply conclude:
$$
D_iF(a,t)=\lim\limits_{x_i\to a_i}\frac{(F\circ\varphi_i)(x_i)-(F\circ\varphi_i)(a_i)}{x_i-a_i}=
\lim\limits_{x_i\to a_i}\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)dt\\=
\lim\limits_{\xi\to a_i}\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)dt=
\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(\varphi_i(a_i),t)dt=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(a,t)dt.
$$

---

Is this correct?

Our professor wrote down a different and lengthier proof in which he shows that the difference between $\frac{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}\left(K(\varphi_i(x_i),t)-K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)\right)dt}{x_i-a_i}$ and $\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}D_iK(a,t)dt$ goes to zero. I am not sure if I have missed something.

Comment: The catch with the above is that the $\xi$ is actually $\xi_t$, as the particular value depends on $t$. If you are using Riemann integration you need to show that the resulting function is Riemann integrable, and similarly with Lebesgue you need to show measurability.

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure to what *resulting function* you refer to? The function $D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)$ is continuous and therefore Riemann-integrable.

Comment: When you apply the mean value theorem, for each $t$ there is some $\xi $ such that $K(\phi_i(x_i),t) - K(\phi_i(a_i),t) = D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)(x_i-a_i)$. The $\xi$ is only guaranteed to work for that particular $t$. So you have that it is a function of $t$.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't understand how your argument should apply here. If I let $\xi\to a_i$ then it doesn't matter if $t$ varies, simply because $\xi_t$ is forced to attain a value very close to $a_i$. So if I consider the limit $\lim\limits_{\xi\to a_i}$ then the equality $K(\varphi_i(\xi),t)-K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)=D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi_t),t)(x_i-a_i)$ will always hold simply because there is no space left for $\xi_t$ to change. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what to say. The MVT applies in the $x$ variable for a particular value of $t$. Hence the resulting $\xi$ is $t$ dependent. You can't assert that the same $\xi$ works for different $t$, it is not hard to create an example that shows it cannot be in general.

Comment: @copper.hat, after a while I came back to this problem. In my opinion your hint is wrong. It doesn't matter if $\xi$ depends on $t$. The function $D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi),t)(x_i-a_i)$ will always be continuous. Note that $K(\varphi_i(\xi),t)-K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)=D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi_t),t)(x_i-a_i)$ and $K(\varphi_i(\xi),t)-K(\varphi_i(a_i),t)$ is continuous by assumption. Even if $\xi$ behaves wildy and jumps the resulting function $D_iK(\varphi_i(\xi_t),t)(x_i-a_i)$ will always be continuous and hence Riemann integrable. The problem lies elsewhere. See my answer.